# DAX - Measure to check if ID has any Type selected from Slicer

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, measure

I have a table that looks like this:

```
ID  Type
1    A
1    B
1    C
2    B
2    B
2    C
3    C    
3    A
4    D
```

I would like to create a measure that tells me, based on a slicer selection that has option from another table with the unique "Type" values, if each ID contains more than one of the selected Type.

The outcome I would like to have, assuming that "B" is selected in the slicer, it the following:

```
ID Type Measure_Outcome
1   A   Yes
1   B   Yes
1   C   Yes
2   B   No
2   B   No
2   C   No
3   C   Yes
3   A   Yes
4   D   No
```

I have put the following together, but it doesn't seem to work. I believe I have a basic misunderstanding of how Measures work:

```
Measure =
VAR _CHECK =
    CALCULATE (
        COUNTROWS ( Table ),
        Table[Type] = MAX ( Sources[Type] ),
        Table[ID] = MAX ( Table[ID] )
    )
RETURN
    IF ( _CHECK > 0, "Yes", "No" )
```

The Source table is the table that includes a summarized table of all the Types.

Would anyone be able to help me create a functioning measure?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved by using:

```
ResultMeasure =
IF (
    ISEMPTY (
        INTERSECT (
            CALCULATETABLE (
                VALUES ( 'Table'[Type] ),
                ALLSELECTED ( 'Table' ),
                VALUES ( 'Table'[ID] )
            ),
            VALUES ( Sources[Type] )
        )
    ),
    "No",
    "Yes"
)
```